# Почему при запуске потока закрывается окно?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Добрый день.

Уже который день пытаюсь понять причину закрытия окна при запуске потока, который никак с этим окном не связан (как мне кажется).

Использую Python 3.5.4 и PyQt 5.6. В главном модуле мы создаём окно с таблицей (tableview). В таблице одна запись. При двойном клике ЛКМ по этой записи открывается пустое окно. Через 5 секунд после запуска программы стартует поток:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import os
import sys
from threads import LoadDocs
from tables import LoadData
from viewwindow import ViewDocs


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Главное окно
        self.main_window = uic.loadUi(os.path.join("main.ui"), self)
        self.main_window.setWindowTitle("Тест")

        # Поток
        self.load_docs_thread = LoadDocs()
        self.load_docs_thread.started.connect(self.load_docs_thread_started)
        self.load_docs_thread.finished.connect(self.load_docs_thread_finished)

        # Таблица
        self.main_window.tableView.doubleClicked.connect(self.open_window)

        value = [("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")]
        table_model = LoadData(value)
        self.main_window.tableView.setModel(table_model)
        self.main_window.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.main_window.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.main_window.tableView.setColumnHidden(0, True)

        # Отображение
        self.main_window.show()

        def open_window(self):
            ViewDocs()

       def load_docs_thread_started(self):
           print("load_docs_thread_started")

def load_docs_thread_finished(self):
    print("load_docs_thread_finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**viewwindow.py**

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic


class ViewDocs(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.view_window = uic.loadUi(os.path.join("viewwindow.ui"), self)
        self.view_window.setWindowTitle("Окно")
        self.view_window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.view_window.show()
```

**threads.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import requests


class LoadDocs(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.basictimer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()
        self.basictimer.start(5000, self)

    def run(self):
        response = requests.get("http://" + "ya.ru")
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("1")

    def timerEvent(self, QTimerEvent):
        self.start()
```

То есть суть проблемы заключается в том, что я запускаю программу и сразу открываю окно дабл кликом по строке таблицы и как только срабатывает поток (проверяет, доступен ли сайт) это окно закрывается, остаётся только главное окно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что в таком случае нужно сделать, чтобы работа потока не влияло на окно?

**Обновлено!** Если создать окно не в Designer, а в самом питоне, то проблема решается:

**viewwindow.py**

```
class ViewDocs(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
```

Comment: У вас отступы при публикации вопроса поломались или так и было? `load_docs_thread_finished` у вас не является методом `MainWindow`, потому что на один уровень отступов левее. Если так и в ваших исходниках, то причина падения, скорее всего, заключается в том что на момент завершения потока `self.load_docs_thread_finished` не определён.

Comment: @fori1ton поломалось, я поправил. Сама программа не падает. Я из главного окна двойным кликом по строке в таблице открываю новое окно, но когда срабатывает поток (выводит "1"), это новое окно закрывается, а главное окно остаётся на месте.

Comment: @fori1ton попробовал сделать просто кнопку в главном окне, при нажатии на которую появляется окно. Это окно при запуске потока не закрывается. Странно.

Comment: Попробовал сделать окно не через Designer, а в самом питоне - создал класс для вызова пустого окна. В таком случае проблема решилась - окно при старте потока не закрывается.